# How to translate wordpress "Page" in breadcrumb and title?

Tags: wordpress, translation

I want to translate wordpress "Page" text in title and breadcrumb.

For example:

- "Page 2 of 10" to "Stran 2 od 10" in title
- "Page 2" to "Stran 2" in breadcrumb

I have already fixed URL from "/page/2/" to "/stran/2/" without problem

See picture below:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7TBi.png)

Comment: It depends on the theme you use I guess

Comment: I'm using flatonpro, but I'm using original WP breadcrumb... Also in theme language files there is no string for that

Comment: It would be easy to find the string called "Home" using your text editor or IDE feature like find in folder feature.

Comment: I've found translation string for "Page x" in breadcrumbs. It was in woocommerce translation file and its called "Page %d". However I'm still unable to find translation string for the title (text in tabs). I've found few strings in theme and WC translation files that are very similar, but translating them change nothing, so I think it's hardcoded text... Any idea?